# Haskell simplification technique and monads

Tags: haskell

How can this code (or in general, code with multiple inputs) can be reduced/simplified?

```
do
  sex    <- askSex
  name   <- askName
  sayHello sex name
```

In this case is very short already, but when it gets to multiple inputs, it looks messy. Is there any way to do something like:

```
sayHello askSex askName
```

?

Comment: This code looks perfectly simple to me

Comment: Everything shorter than this will most likely be bizarre. If you were asking for a lot of the same kind of inputs, you might map over those actions, but not in this case.

Comment: Check out the functions in [`Control.Monad`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html), specifically `liftM2`.

Comment: As sabauma says, use `liftM2`.  It's an abstraction of your original code and just what you want.

Comment: n.b. It is clearer if you include the `do` from the start of the do-block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a lovely time for Applicative Functors:

```
import Control.Applicative -- at the top of your module before any functions

hello "Male" name = "Hi, " ++ name ++ ", that's a cool name."
hello "Female" name = "Hello, " ++ name ++ ", that's a pretty name."

greet = hello <$> askSex <*> askName >>= putStrLn
```

It works a bit like `fmap` in the previous answers I gave you today, but for larger numbers of arguments, like you have here.

Using functions like my `hello` with applicative functors helps you separate your IO code from the rest of the code, which is very good practice. Try to write `hello` instead of `sayHello` every time.

Answer (score 5):

If you

```
import Control.Applicative  -- for <$> and <*>
import Control.Monad        -- for join
```

you can write

```
join $ sayHello <$> askSex <*> askName
```

For your example, where you are only fetching two parameters, this is not a big win. But for a greater number of parameters it can make the code clearer.

```
join $ doSomething <$> getFirst <*> getSecond <*> getThird <*> getForth
```

Comment: It's a shame idiom brackets haven't made it into Haskell: `join (|doSomething getFirst getSecond getThird getForth|)` would be much nicer.

Comment: Well, there's always [the quasiquoter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/applicative-quoters)

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, hoogle doesn't have an easy answer for this one. This would be called `bind2`. If it's a function with only one input, then you can use `=<<`, the infix version of what I'd call `bind1`.

```
sayHello =<< askName
```

But for multiple inputs, we're out of luck. For whatever reason, the standard libs don't provide this:

```
bind2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
bind2 f mx my = do
  x <- mx
  y <- my
  f x y

...

bind2 sayHello askSex askName
```

You can, of course, just define it yourself.