# The Haskell RNG and state

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming, state, monads

As a Java person learning Haskell I was getting use to the new way of thinking about everything but I've spent half a day trying to implement something with a simple RNG and am getting nowhere. In Java I could crate a static RNG and call it with Classname.random.nextInt(10) and it would meet these criteria:

1. I wouldn't have to keep a reference to the RNG and I could call it ad-hoc (even from inside a loop or a recursive function)
2. It would produce a new random number every time it was called
3. It would produce a new set of random numbers every time the project executed

So far in Haskell I'm facing the classic programmers dilemma - I can have 2/3. I'm still learning and have absolutely no idea about Monads, except that they *might* be able to help me here.

My Most recent attempt has been this:

```
getRn :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Int -> Rand g Int
getRn lo hi= getRandomR (lo,hi)
```

--EDIT: Trimming my questions so that it's not so long winded, replacing with a summary and then what I ended up doing instead:

After creating a bunch of random cities (for TSP), I maped over them with a function `createEdges` that took a city and connected it to the rest of the cities: `M.mapWithKey (\x y -> (x,(createEdges y [1..3] makeCountry)))`

PROBLEM:

I wanted to replace [1..3] with something random. I.e. I wanted to map randomness (IO) over pure code. This caused no end of confusion for me (see people's attempt to answer me below to get a good sense of my confusion). In fact I'm still not even sure if I'm explaining the problem correctly.

I was getting this type of error: `Couldn't match expected type [Int] with actual type IO [Int]`

SOLUTION:

So after finding out that what I wanted to do was fundamentally wrong in a functional environment, I decided to change my approach. Instead of generating a list of cities and then applying randomness to connect them, I instead created an [[Int]] where each inner list represented the random edges. Thereby creating my randomness at the start of the process, rather than trying to map randomness over the pure code.

**(I posted the final result as my own answer, but SO won't let me accept my own answer yet. Once it does I've reached that threshold I'll come back and accept)**

Comment: Haha, well I guess I should have said "it is great right until I get super frustrated coz I can't work it out". I'm just use to finding the hard things hard and the easy things easy, Haskell is feeling like the other way around.

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive: There are many functions which have neither definition nor type signature. Could you at least add the proposed types for `createEdgeCount`, `createEdges`, `makeCountry`, `citiesExcludeSelf`, even though they don't typecheck? (Also `City`, `Country`)

Comment: A historical comment: the first OO language, Simula, did it in a similar way to Haskell; you have to carry the RNG state around yourself.

Comment: It's much easier to map pure code over random data than map random code over pure data, so definitely continue with that approach. You could make two random lists (one of lengths, one of edges) and pull them together with a fully lazy pure function like `multiTake :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]` with `multiTake (l:ls) vs = chunk : multiTake ls remainder where (chunk,remainder) = splitAt l vs`. You could use that with `liftM2 multiTake (getRandomRs (3,7)) (getRandomRs (lo, hi))`

Comment: Also you'll find life easier if you separate the pure bit (eg `multiTake`) from the random bit - only every write code for one item and then use `map` and `liftM2` etc to get lots, or random ones.

Comment: If you were able to solve the problem yourself, answer your own question and accept it. This will tidy things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: After a lot more reading and some extra help from a friend, I finally reduced it to this solution. However I'll keep my original solution in the answer as well just in case the same approach helps another newbie like me (it was a vital part of my learning process as well).

```
-- Use a unique random generator (replace <$> newStdGen with mkStdGen 123 for testing)
generateTemplate = createCitiesWeighted <$> newStdGen

-- create random edges (with weight as pair) by taking a random sized sample of randoms
multiTakePair :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [[(Int,Int)]]
multiTakePair ws (l:ls) is = (zip chunka chunkb) : multiTakePair remaindera ls remainderb
    where
        (chunkb,remainderb) = splitAt l is
        (chunka,remaindera) = splitAt l ws

-- pure version of utilizing multitake by passing around an RNG using "split"
createCitiesWeighted :: StdGen -> [[(Int,Int)]]
createCitiesWeighted gen = take count result
    where
        (count,g1) = randomR (15,20) gen
        (g2,g3) = split g1
        cs = randomRs (0, count - 2) g1
        es = randomRs (3,7) g2
        ws = randomRs (1,10) g3
        result = multiTakePair ws es cs
```

The original solution -----

As well as @user2407038's insightful comments, my solution relied very heavily on what I read from these two questions:

- [Sampling sequences of random numbers in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110535/sampling-sequences-of-random-numbers-in-haskell)
- [Random Integer in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535657/random-integer-in-haskell)

(NB. I was having an issue where I couldn't work out how to randomize how many edges each city would have, @AnrewC provided an awesome response that not only answered that question but massively reduce excess code)

```
module TspRandom (
    generateCityTemplate
) where

import Control.Monad (liftM, liftM2) -- promote a pure function to a monad


-- @AndrewC's suggestion
multiTake :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [[Int]]
multiTake (l:ls) is = chunk : multiTake ls remainder
    where (chunk,remainder) = splitAt l is

-- Create a list [[Int]] where each inner int is of a random size (3-7)
-- The values inside each inner list max out at 19 (total - 1)
createCities = liftM (take 20) $ liftM2 multiTake (getRandomRs (3,7)) (getRandomRs (0, 19))

-- Run the generator
generateCityTemplate = do
    putStrLn "Calculating # Cities"
    x <- createCities
    print x
    return ()
```

Comment: The key lesson from how nice `multiTake` makes the code is: Separate your pure processing functions (in this case using two lists of random numbers to make a list of lists of random numbers) from the production and output. The more you do this, the neater things get.

Comment: For more functional style brownie points, `import Control.Applicative` and define `createCities = fmap ( take 20 ) $ multiTake <$> getRandomRs (3,7) <*> getRandomRs (0, 19)` See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243303/haskell-simplification-technique-and-monads) for what it translates to. Using `<$>` and `<*>` you can replace as many `liftM`, `liftM2`, `liftM3` as you like.

Comment: I'd just read about applicative's in Learn you a Haskell but didn't really understand it. But re-reading after trying to solve this problem really helped me understand. Also was useful having a friend explain it to me, some things are just harder to grasp reading lessons! the <$> and <*> would have been a useful replacement for liftM, will keep that in mind for next time though. I found a way to juggle passing around an RNG and use an IO StdGen only for the first one. See my update above. Thanks for all the help mate!

Answer (score 2):

You can work with random numbers without any monads or IO at all if you like.
All you have to know is, that as there is state (internal state of the random-number-generator) involved you have to *take* this state with you.

In my opinion the easiest framework for this is [Sytem.Random](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.2/docs/System-Random.html).

Using this your `getRn` function could look like this:

```
getRn :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Int -> g -> (Int, g)
getRn lo hi g = randomR (lo,hi) g
```

here you can view `g` as the *state* I mentioned above - you put it in and you get another back like this (in ghci):

```
> let init = mkStdGen 11
> let (myNr, nextGen) = getRn 1 6 init
> myNr
6
> let (myNr, nextGen') = getRn 1 6 nextGen
> myNr
4
```

I think you can start by using just this - thread the `gen` around and later when you get all the monad stuff come back and make it a bit easier to write/read.

I don't know the definitions of your data but here is a simple example that uses this technique:

```
module StackOQuestion where

import System.Random

getRn :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Int -> g -> (Int, g)
getRn lo hi = randomR (lo,hi)

getRnList :: (RandomGen g) => (g -> (a, g)) -> Int -> g -> ([a], g)
getRnList f n g
  | n <= 0    = ([], g)
  | otherwise = let (ls, g') = getRnList f (n-1) g
                    (a, g'') = f g'
                in  (a:ls, g'')

type City = (Int, Int)

randomCity :: (RandomGen g) => g -> (City, g)
randomCity g =
    let (f, g')  = getRn 1 6 g
        (s, g'') = getRn 1 6 g'
    in  ((f, s), g'')

randomCities :: (RandomGen g) => (Int, Int) -> g -> ([City], g)
randomCities (minC, maxC) g = 
  let (count, g') = getRn minC maxC g 
  in getRnList randomCity count g'
```

and you can test it like this:

```
> let init = mkStdGen 23
> randomCities (2,6) init
([(4,3),(1,2)],394128088 652912057)
```

As you can see this creates two *Cities* (here simply represented as an integer-pair) - for other values of `init` you will get other answers.

If you look the right way at this you can see that there is already the beginning of a *state-monad* there (the `g -> ('a, g)` part) ;)

PS: `mkStdGen` is a bit like the Random-initialization you know from Java and co (the part where you usually put your system-clock's tick-count in) - I choose 11 because it was quick to type ;) - of course you will always get the same numbers if you stick with 11 - so you will need to initialize this with something from IO - but you can push this pack to `main` and keep pure otherwise if you just pass then `g` around

Comment: I've gone for Control.Monad.Random over System.Random to avoid passing around a StdGen.

My trouble is specifically with this bit: `M.mapWithKey (\x y -> (x,(createEdges y [1..3] makeCountry)))`

In that [1..3] I want take a list of cities, then do this:
> Create a set of cities excluding itself
> Select a random sized, non-contiguous subset
> For each city in the subset check if there is an existing edge between the two
> If not, return a new "country" of cities which has the edges created.

I'm not really sure how to pass around the random gen in that setup

Comment: Added an edit to my answer to clarify. Hopefully that makes a bit more sense?

Comment: Well I thought I give you an option to stay out of monad-land - but ok let's see: Your createEdges here should be random right? I think that's to much trouble.

Comment: based on your answer and @user2407038 below, I guess that means there's no way to map randomness over a list?

Comment: If that's the case I will have to rethink the approach to the problem. Maybe I can create a random infinite list at the same time that I create the city count and use (c:cs) from that list to create the edges at the same time as creating the cities. I can then backtrack and connect the random numbers to their destinations (which I can't do until the destinations exist)

Comment: Of course you can map randomness over a list. Here's an random list `rnds lo hi gen = let (x, gen') = randomR (lo, hi) gen in x : rnds lo hi gen'`. Here's a function which randomly permutes an input list `perm inp gen = let (g1, g2) = split gen in (zipWith (+) inp (rnds 0 10 g1), g2)`. Passing `StdGen` state around is easy and you can abstract over it to hide it if you like: `newtype Random a = Random { runRandom :: g -> (a, g) }`. Now you have `splitR :: Random StdGen; splitR = Random split` and `rndsR :: Int -> Int -> Random [Int]; rndsR lo hi = Random (rnds lo hi)`.

Comment: Manipulating the `Random` type can be slightly tricky. I recommend the following combinators to make it easier: `constant :: a -> Random a; constant a = Random (\gen -> (a, gen))` which does nothing with the `gen`; `mapR :: (a -> b) -> Random a -> Random b; mapR f (Random go) = Random (\gen -> let (a, gen') = go gen in (f a, gen'))` which lets you transform the thing "inside the `Random`" just like it were a list; and `choiceR :: Random a -> (a -> Random b) -> Random b; choiceR (Random go) f = Random (\gen -> let (a, gen') = go gen in runRandom (f a) gen')` which lets you sequence `Random`s.

Comment: With practice, you'll find those combinators *very* expressive. Here's an example you can build atop them: `togetherR :: [Random a] -> Random [a]; togetherR [] = constant []; togetherR (r:rs) = choiceR r (\a -> togetherR rs (\as -> constant (a:as)))`. You can use this example to make random lists, for instance.

Comment: maybe you should provide another answer ... I don't think many will find your good points in the comments here

Comment: @CarstenKönig I don't think I've actually answered his question, though! Just given food for thought... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would say if you want to work with random numbers, the easiest thing to do is to use an utility library like [`Control.Monad.Random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.13/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html).

The more educational, work intensive path is to learn to write your own monad like that.  First you want to understand the `State` monad and get comfortable with it.  I think studying [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658443/how-to-decorate-a-tree-in-haskell) (disclaimer: I have an answer there) may be a good starting point for studying this.  The next step I would take is to be able to write the `State` monad on my own.

After that, the next exercise I would try is to write a "utility" monad for random number generation.  By "utility" monad what I mean is a monad that basically repackages the standard `State` monad with an API that makes it easier for that specific task.  This is how that `Control.Monad.Random` package is implemented:

```
-- | A monad transformer which adds a random number generator to an
-- existing monad.
newtype RandT g m a = RandT (StateT g m a)
```

Their `RandT` monad is really just a `newtype` definition that reuses `StateT` and adds a few utility functions so that you can concentrate on *using* random numbers rather than on the state monad itself.  So for this exercise, you basically design a random number generation monad with the API you'd like to have, then use the `State` and `Random` libraries to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The state monad is actually very simple. It is just a function from a state to a value and a new state, or:

```
data State s a = State {getState :: s -> (s, a)}
```

In fact, this is exactly what the `Rand` monad is. It isn't necessary to understand the mechanics of `State` to use `Rand`. You shouldn't be evaluating the `Rand` inside of `IO`, just use it directly, using the same `do` notation you have been using for `IO`. `do` notation works for *any* monad.

```
createCities :: Rand StdGen Int 
createCities = getRn minCities maxCities

x :: Cities -> X
x = ...

func :: Rand StdGen X
func = do 
  cities <- createCities
  return (x cities)

-- also valid
func = cities <$> createCities
func = createCities >>= return . x
```

You can't write `getConnections` like you have written it. You must do the following:

```
getConnections :: City -> Country -> Rand StdGen [Int]
getConnections c country = do 
  edgeCount <- createEdgeCount 
  fromIndecies [] edgeCount (citiesExcludeSelf c country)
```

Any function which calls `getConnections` will have to also return a value of type `Rand StdGen x`. You can only get rid of it once you have written the entire algorithm and want to run it.

Then, you can run the result using `evalRandIO func`, or, if you want to test some algorithm and you want to give it the same inputs on every test, you can use `evalRand func (mkStdGen 12345)`, where 12345, or any other number, is your seed value.

Comment: Let me see if I can understand this... Is the mistake that I'm making trying to evaluate the random result from inside the do statement? So I should try moving the code that does all the random work into where you have x =..., and call that from the do?

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive What is "evaluate the random result from inside the do statement"? Your example doesn't make much sense, since you say `getConnections` is called recursively, but it isn't used anywhere in your example code. I tried updating my answer to better address your question anyways.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I am trying to run it inside of a map function... something like this: `map (createRandomEdges) cityList`. I am guessing that because createRandomEdges is IO, I can't map the effects of IO onto a list?

Comment: As I said above: If that's the case I will have to rethink the approach to the problem. Maybe I can create a random infinite list at the same time that I create the city count and use (c:cs) from that list to create the edges at the same time as creating the cities. I can then backtrack and connect the random numbers to their destinations (which I can't do until the destinations exist)

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive Sounds good: make random data, then combine it with with other data.

Comment: @TheCriticalImperitive That is what I usually do when I need an unknown amount of random numbers, create an infinite list: `map (fst . randomR (a,b)) . unfoldr (Just . split)`. You can still map a function which produces a monadic result, just use `mapM` from `Control.Monad` instead of `map`.